# ASP.NET Core Typescript importing external modules eg. ui-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ui-grid

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I started writing Web application using Angular.
I set up project from VS template.

I tried to import ui-grid.
I found, that it should be done with

```
npm install @types/ui-grid --save
```

Then I tried to import it inside my module in different ways.

```
import * as uiGrid from 'ui-grid';
```

I also created typescript controller using ui-grid documentation

```
@Component({
selector: 'workers',
templateUrl: './workers.component.html'
})
export class WorkersComponent {
    myData = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney"
    }];
}
```

and html

```
<div >
    <div ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
```

I tried also other configurations.
The problem is nothing displayed on web page.
I spent two evenings trying to force it to work, but unsuccessfully...

Controller is working properly, because simple text binding is working.

I didn't find any tutorial epxlaining how to import modules from DefinitlyTyped...

If anyone could explain how to do it and what am I doing wrong, I would really appreciate that :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
npm install --save angular-ui-grid
```

to install the js lib, so in the .ts file add

```
require('angular-ui-grid');
```

I use webpack and work.